# CreateTable does not create PrimaryKey nor Foreign Kety Constraits

Tags: sqlite-net-extensions

I created a simple project. Aded the Sqlite and Sqlite extensons. However when I create the tables. Neither Primary nor ForeignKey relation is established on the table. 
Could someone let me know what am I doing wrong.

```
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("me4.db", SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        connection.Execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON");
        connection.Commit();

        connection.CreateTable<Group>();
        connection.CreateTable<UserGroup>();
```

[image]

```
[Table("group")]
public class Group
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public string Descripton { get; set; }

    public bool IsPublic { get; set; }

    public string SmtpAddress { get; set; }

    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }

}

[Table("usergroup")]
public class UserGroup
{
    public bool IsFavorite{ get; set; }

    public string LastVisitedTime { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Group),Unique=true)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite.Net doesn't have support for Foreign Keys, SQLite-Net Extensions uses `Indexed` properties under the hood.

Primary Keys work as expected, not sure why your database browser is not showing it.

To check it, you can try this code:

```
var group = new Group { Id = 1 };
connection.Insert(group); // Element inserted
connection.Insert(group); // ERROR: constrain violation
```